# Glued acronyms and golang naming convention

Tags: go, naming-conventions, acronym

Is there a way to make the constants below to be more readable without breaking golang naming convention?

```
const ( // stream types
    MPEGDASHStream  = iota
    HLSStream       = iota
    MPEGTSUDPStream = iota
    MPEGTSRTPStream = iota
)
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you use underscores? `MPEG_DASH_STREAM`

Comment: That's logical, but I doubt it's recommended.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to make them more readable without breaking the code style. I'd suggest sticking to want you have, and maybe take icza's advice and put `Stream` in front of constants.

Comment: My advice: readability is more important than dogmatic adherence to a particular code style. In this case something like `MpegDASHStream` or `MPEGDashStream` seems like an acceptable compromise.

Answer (score 18):

Go's naming convention prefers MixedCaps rather than underscores, so don't use them. Source: [Effective Go: MixedCaps](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#mixed-caps)

Usually when you have constants for different values of an entity, a more easily readable way is to start constant names with the entity, which is then followed by the name of the concrete value. Great examples are the [`net/http`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/) package:

```
const (
    MethodGet  = "GET"
    MethodHead = "HEAD"
    MethodPost = "POST"
    // ...
)

const (
    StatusContinue           = 100 // RFC 7231, 6.2.1
    StatusSwitchingProtocols = 101 // RFC 7231, 6.2.2
    StatusProcessing         = 102 // RFC 2518, 10.1

    StatusOK                 = 200 // RFC 7231, 6.3.1
    StatusCreated            = 201 // RFC 7231, 6.3.2
    // ...
)
```

Also you don't need to repeat the expression with `iota` identifier. [Spec: Constant declarations:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Constant_declarations)

> Within a parenthesized `const` declaration list the expression list may be omitted from any but the first declaration. Such an empty list is equivalent to the textual substitution of the first preceding non-empty expression list and its type if any. Omitting the list of expressions is therefore equivalent to repeating the previous list.

So in your case it could simply look like this, which is quite clear and readable:

```
// stream types
const (
    StreamMPEGDASH = iota
    StreamHLS
    StreamMPEGTSUDP
    StreamMPEGTSRTP
)
```

Also see [Go Code Review Comments](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CodeReviewComments) for more details. Acronyms can be found in the [Initialisms](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CodeReviewComments#initialisms) section:

> Words in names that are initialisms or acronyms (e.g. "URL" or "NATO") have a consistent case. For example, "URL" should appear as "URL" or "url" (as in "urlPony", or "URLPony"), never as "Url". Here's an example: ServeHTTP not ServeHttp.
>
> This rule also applies to "ID" when it is short for "identifier," so write "appID" instead of "appId".

Comment: Yes, but what about sequenced acronyms? They make them quite unreadable.

Comment: I like this better! The effective go webpage also says this:

Comment: "MixedCaps

Finally, the convention in Go is to use MixedCaps or mixedCaps rather than underscores to write multiword names."

Comment: MixedCaps is OK, but the rule about uppercasing acronyms can produce unreadable sequences without visual separation.

Answer (score 13):

What you do is the canonical Golang way.

According to [Code Review Comments](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CodeReviewComments#initialisms), you should string the acronyms in `ALLCAPS`:

> Words in names that are initialisms or acronyms (e.g. "URL" or "NATO") have a consistent case. For example, "URL" should appear as "URL" or "url" (as in "urlPony", or "URLPony"), never as "Url". As an example: ServeHTTP not ServeHttp. For identifiers with multiple initialized "words", use for example "xmlHTTPRequest" or "XMLHTTPRequest".

Do I like it? Not so much.

You could move the words around a bit to make it more readable, e.g. `MPEGStreamDASH`

If you really hate it - then you need to realize it's your code and you can do whatever you like - be it `MpegDashStream`, `MPEG_DASH_Stream` or even `MpEg_DaSh_StreaM` - but that would be evil ;-)

Answer (score 0):

My understanding from https://google.github.io/styleguide/go/decisions.html (specifically `each initialism in the name does not need to have the same case`) is that `MPEGdashStream` would be correct.